# Algorithm to distribute heartbeats?

Tags: algorithm, networking, network-programming, load-balancing

I am building a sensor network where a large number of sensors report their status to a central hub. The sensors need to report status atleast once every 3 hours, but I want to make sure that the hub does not get innundated with too many reports at any given time. So to mitigate this, I let the hub tell the sensors the 'next report time'.

Now I am looking for any standard algorithms for doing some load balancing of these updates, such that the sensors dont exceed a set interval between reports and the hub can calculate the next report time such that its load (of receiving reports) is evenly divided over the day.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many sensors there are, just divide up every three hour chunk into that many time slots and (either randomly or programmatically as you need), assign one to each sensor.

If you don't, you can still divide up every three hour chunk into some large number of time slots and assign them to sensors.  In your assignment algorithm, you just have to make sure that all the slots have one assigned sensor before any of them have two, and all of them have two before any of them have three, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution: Is there any reason why the hub cannot poll the sensors according to its own schedule?

Otherwise you may want to devise a system where the hub can decide whether or not to accept a report based on its own load. If a sensor has its connection denied make it wait an random period of time and retry. Over time the sensors should space themselves out more or less optimally.

IIRC some facet of TCP/IP uses a similar method, but I'm drawing a blank as to which.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of ethernet's [exponential backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff#An_example_of_an_exponential_backoff_algorithm) algorithm

Comment: Sensors may be added or removed without the hub knowing about it - so would not be able to use the poll solution. Rate-limiting and retry would work but the communication overhead is not ideal for my use case. Thanks for the ideas though

Answer (score 0):

I would use a base of 90 minutes with a randomized variation over a 30-minute range, so that the intervals are randomly beteween 60 and 120 minutes. Adjust these numbers if you want to get closer to the 3-hour interval but I would personally stay well under it